# How to refer same namespace in XAML file?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xml-namespaces

This question is related to a WPF application.

I have a class as below in Project "**Common**". Namespace name is also same.

```
namespace Common
{
   public ViewBase : UserControl
   {
     // Code
   }
}
```

If I add a new abc.XAML file to same project (**Common**)...I would like to derive my code behind class(abc.xaml.cs file) from ViewBase class.

But in this case how do I write my header in XAML file ?

That is...how should refer my current namepace?

```
<Namespace:ViewBase x:Class=""
  xmlns:x=""
  ....>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare the namespace using [`xmlns` mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx), it is "active" in the current element as well, so the namespace can be used in the tag of the element declaring it. e.g.

```
<ns:ViewBase xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:Common" ...>
```

Comment: if I do that, it says i dont have a reference to that.

Comment: the project reference. I mean if we add another namespace, we have to add that referenc right.

Comment: @Relativity: Build your project and any warnings/errors relating will go away.

Comment: @Relativity: If you need a reference, add it, if the namesapce is in another assembly, reference the assembly, read the docs i linked to.

Comment: @Relativity what H.B. is suggesting, I think, is to add a reference to the assembly. Look at the following example: `xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:SDKSample;assembly=SDKSampleLibrary"`. Note the `;assembly=SDKSampleLibrary"` on the end. This is used if the assembly is required in the namespace reference. Try doing something like that in your code.